# Use a different confidence interval in ggplot2 mean_cl_boot

Tags: r, ggplot2

`ggplot2` uses `Hmisc:smean_cl_boot` in its `stat_summary` as

```
stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_boot, geom = "pointrange")
```

Is it possible to specify a 90% confidence interval instead of the default 95? In `Hmisc::smean_cl_boot` it is an option, but I don't know how to pass it through the `ggplot2` syntax. I prefer not to define a custom function.

Comment: Not sure, but does this work: `stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_boot, conf.int = .90, geom = "pointrange")`? Edit: Didn't see @NicE's comment yet..

Comment: @NicE please add your comment as an answer if you want.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `fun.args` argument of `stat_summary` to pass arguments to the function.

Try:

```
stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_boot, geom = "pointrange",fun.args=list(conf.int=.9))
```